# How to stop ReportViewer control (VS 2010) from html encoding my links

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I have a reporting services report with a url with querystring parameters in a column.  When it is accessed directly through reporting services, all is well.  I click on the url and it goes to the appropriate page.

However, when I access the report through the ReportViewer control in VS 2010, the ampersand in my link is html encoded.  So the querystring parameters

```
?value1=abc&value2=def
```

become

```
?value1=abc&amp;value2=def
```

This is messing up my report.  How do I stop the ReportViewer from HtmlEncoding the results?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have just encountered this and found a simple yet unsatisfying solution:

Create a text expression like this:

```
=Replace(Fields!MyDbField.Value ,"amp;","")
```

Not elegant but it works and it is unlikely you will have a string with the actual real value of "amp;"